# Which way is better to implement a thread-safe Counter in a database?

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTER (ID VARCHAR(256), VALUE INT)
```

where ID is the primary key.

I want to implement a mechanism for incrementing and getting the current value of the counter that is thread safe. The counters will be created by the application, there will be many of them. There are many instances of the application with many threads running and they can increment the same counter at the same time.

Which way is better:

1. Serializable transactions with update to increment and then select to get the value
2. Optimistic locking (transaction isolation shouldn't matter here) - in a loop: select current value, try to update where value = current value

Or is there a completely better way to do this?

Comment: The safest way is to use built-in sequences, which most databases support.

Comment: So anytime I would do an insert in this table, I should create a sequence instead?

Comment: Most databases also have some form of identity or auto-increment columns that do essentially the same thing.

Comment: It depends on your sql dialect, but any write should result in a row-level lock. An `UPDATE` statement can refer to the existing value, thereby avoiding a racy read. An `INSERT.. ON CONFLICT UPDATE` can be a useful variant. If you are doing more complex work, then `SELECT FOR UPDATE` obtains the exclusive row lock so that an update can be performed later in the transaction when the new value is known.

Comment: @GordonLinoff auto-increment columns realize a different need, in my case by inserting a new row I meant creating a new counter, which will later be updated.

Comment: @BenManes update refering to the existing value will work, but I won't know what the value was after my update, and a select after can already return a totally different value

Comment: In Postgres there is a RETURNING clause which is what I do, but forgot it’s dialect specific. You should be able to read your write within the transaction because it holds the row lock. Just make sure not to use auto commit, obviously.